# Django todoApp coming problem in adding task

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, tailwind-css

I am getting problems with added tasks. It shows MultiValueDictKeyError in my code.

Here is my source code -- https://github.com/Aliwahid17/todoApp

Please help me in solving the problem.

Comment: update  your question with the code  that has the problem you ask , the views part  and the html

Comment: it showing me problem in views.py file

Answer (score 0):

Your have not a good described question, the codebase and error message should be here, not on the repository, but i can answer.

problem is in index.html :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkedbox" id="{{todo.id}}" class="taskCheckbox" value="{{todo.id}}">
```

after that you try in view.py:

```
  checkedlist = request.POST["checkedbox"]
```

It is famous behavior for Checkbox: if your check box not "checked", browser don't send the 'checkedbox' key.

You are simply don't has in request key 'checkedbox', you can see it yourself in debugger before the ask. :)